# Is Magnanimous Right in this Context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

While I was in high school, my English teacher once used ***magnanimous*** in a statement to mean *huge/large*. But after [checking the meaning of it recently](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/magnanimous), it doesn't seem to mean what I thought it meant, so I need to know if it was right in the context.

The full statement was:

> A magnanimous conflagration is engulfing my edifice, please report to
>   my domicile pronto.

I believe that this is supposed to mean:

> A huge fire is burning my mansion, please report to my home
>   immediately.

That is, it was a joke and intended for a call to the fire fighters.

Beyond the above statement, I have seen same used on a [Trip Advisor Review](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowUserReviews-g187371-d192291-r291437793-Cologne_Cathedral-Cologne_North_Rhine_Westphalia.html) to mean big, and some [twitter posts](https://twitter.com/elitesignsindia/status/946349309867339776) with same intent.
Also Definition at [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/magnanimous) stated **big** as part of its synonyms.

Putting all this in mind, My question is; 
Is my teacher's statement correct?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81923/discussion-on-question-by-julius-is-magnanimous-right-in-this-context).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of magnanimous in describing large buildings](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/454613).

Comment: @jsw29 This question statement context is different from the stated question link, and aside that, the linked question wasn't answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the whole thing *is*, as a number of people have commented on, a joke.

The humour is subtle, and primarily absurdist in nature, in that no sane person who wants the firefighters to come quickly would use such florid language.

The whole thing would fit in well in today's world as a parody of those who are a little too quick to consult a *thesaurus* but not validate the results using a combination of *dictionary* and *reading enough to be familiar with real-life usage of the words found*.

Indeed the intended meaning is ***generous***, as in *ample* or *substantial*, or just plain *big*.

[Note: **all** the words are used with "correct" meanings, they're just completely "unidiomatic" **in the context**]